# Docusign API - Can we create Document Custom field from Rest API

Tags: docusignapi

I saw we have API calls to create / list Envelope Custom fields. 
https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Accounts/AccountCustomFields/

Is there a call to create Document Custom field to populate in the Admin section , so that we can use it in any template .
https://admindemo.docusign.com/custom-fields

[Admin section screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzOwE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the operation you're looking for is **Create Custom Tabs**, which is defined here in the docs:  https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/CustomTabs/CustomTabs/create.

The following request creates a new Document Custom Field called "AccountID" that's a required Text Tab with maximum length of 10.

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/tab_definitions

{
    "tabLabel": "AccountID",
    "maximumLength": "10",
    "required": "true",
    "type": "Text",
}
```

After this request is executed, the new field (**AccountID**) is listed on the **Document Custom Fields** page within the DocuSign web UI (and is available for use in Templates and Envelopes).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kim. This was what I was looking for . One more question related to this. Is there an option to bulk import all the custom tabs , instead of one by one .

Comment: Happy I could help.  To the best of my knowledge, it's not possible to create multiple custom fields with a single API request -- you'll need to issue a separate API request for each custom field that you want to create.

Comment: Thanks Kim for your help. I will do single API call to create custom field 

Comment: Hi Kim, I need help with this question. Will u be able to check this for me  - List template using user filter that are owned and shared with me
https://stackoverflow.com/q/49058297/9284389?sem=2