# List template using user filter that are owned and shared with me

Tags: docusignapi

I need to get the list of template that are owned by me and shared with me . When I used user_filter=shared_with_me , i get all the list of templates from everyone Admin User in my account.

If i have 3 admin users in my docusign account
UserA has TemplateA setup
UserB has TemplateB setup
UserC has TemplateC setup

If  UserC shared TemplateC with UserA

Is it possible to get the list of template for UserA as *TemplateA* and *TemplateC*.

Based on user_filter=shared_with_me ,UserA , if get TemplateA, TemplateB AND TemplateC

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/Templates/list) defines the valid values for the `user_filter` parameter like this:

> Valid values are:
>
> - **owned_by_me**: only shows templates the user owns.
> - **shared_with_me**: only shows templates that are shared with the user.
> - **all**: shows all templates owned or shared with the user.

Based on this, you should be able to achieve what you're trying to achieve by using the query string parameter `user_filter=all`.

`GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates?user_filter=all`